# Достать элементы из нескольких списков в одну строку

Tags: python, циклы, коллекции, python-2.7

Всем привет, столкнулся с задачей, есть 3 списка, из каждого списка нужно достать первый элемент, и добавить в строку, и так далее с шагом +1, пытался решить таким способом (см. код ниже)

```
first_list = ['10', '11', '12']
second_list = ['21', '22', '23']
third_list = ['34', '35', '36']

def main():
    list_index = 0
    while len(third_list):
        command_string = "some_data: "
        for elem in first_list:
            str1 = command_string + elem[list_index] + " "
            for elem in second_list:
                str2 = str1 + elem[list_index] + " "
                for elem in third_list:
                    str3 = str2 + elem[list_index] + " "
        print(str3)
        list_index = list_index + 1
```

но на выходе получаю просто первые цифры елементов списка, и ошибку:

```
some_data: 1 2 3 
some_data: 2 3 6 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 11, in main
    str1 = command_string + elem[list_index] + " "
IndexError: string index out of range
```

В результате ожидаю подобноую строку: "some_data: первый элемент первого списка. первый элемент второго списка, и тд" , "some_data: второй элемент первого списка. второй элемент второго списка, и тд"
списков может быть больше чем три. списки одинаковых размеров.
буду благодарен за подсказки, спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ожидаемый результат

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, но лучше не текстом описывать а строкой, типо из консоли :)

Comment: благодарю за подсказку, я вообще ожидал увидеть ответ завтра после обеда, а не прям через минуту

Comment: Так сошлись звезды, что вы написали прямо перед тем как мне захотелось поглядеть что нового на стеке :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно итерировать сразу по всем циклам

Через [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
first_list = ['10', '11', '12']
second_list = ['21', '22', '23']
third_list = ['34', '35', '36']

for value in zip(first_list, second_list, third_list):
    print('some_data: ' + ' '.join(value))
```

Консоль:

```
some_data: 10 21 34
some_data: 11 22 35
some_data: 12 23 36
```

---

Или через циклы (для python3 вместо `xrange` использовать `range`):

```
arrays = [
    ['10', '11', '12'],
    ['21', '22', '23'],
    ['34', '35', '36'],
    ['11', '12', '32'],
]

for i in xrange(len(arrays[0])):
    value = ' '.join(sub[i] for sub in arrays)
    print('some_data: ' + value)
```

Консоль:

```
some_data: 10 21 34 11
some_data: 11 22 35 12
some_data: 12 23 36 32
```

Comment: можно ли добавить указатель на таблицу, например: print('some_data: ' + ' '.join(value(first_list) + ' '.join(value(second_list)))?

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите. Что должно получиться?

Comment: мне нужно между value еще знаки, чтоб получилось например так: 'some_data: {value} - {value} - {value}!'

Comment: @Merser5, `print('some_data: ' + ' - '.join(value) + '!')`?

Answer (score 0):

Через индексы:

```
first_list = ['10', '11', '12']
second_list = ['21', '22', '23']
third_list = ['34', '35', '36']

for n in range(len(first_list)):
    print("some_data: {{{0}}} - {{{1}}} - {{{2}}}!".format(first_list[n], second_list[n], third_list[n]))
# some_data: {10} - {21} - {34}!
```

Comment: а есть возможность через указатели, опеределить к какому списку принадлежит переменная?

Comment: не понял, какая переменная? здесь 4 списка и одна переменная n - для номера индекса. Если про элементы - то первый для первого, второй для второго, третий для третьего))

Comment: 1. я сам борюсь, и не могу решить и найти инфу в нете) 2. у меня есть 8 списков, нужно взять первый элемент из каждого списка, и добавить в строку, есть готово! 3. но между элементами нужно поставить знаки, а после последенего закрывающий знак, вот я сейчас пытаюсь узнать как указать что первый элемент из списка 1 второй из списка 2, но между ними нужно поставить знаки, я пытаюсь узнать как указать на список 1  после элемента добавить знак, указать на список 2 после элемента добавить знак, и тд пример как у меня сейчас ниже

Comment: while i == len(list1):
        for value in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8):
            print(some_command + ''.join(value))
            i = i + 1
        print(i)

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(itertools.chain(*zip(first_list, second_list, third_list)))  # 102134112235122336
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q = [first_list, second_list, third_list] #вообще говоря, произвольное кол-во
list(zip(*q))[0]
```